# How could I disable rails 4 verbose log , esp cache miss/hit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

My rails console is full of the cache logs.

How could I make it quiet , thanks

```
Started GET "/assets/lms/wp-content/themes/lms/framework/js/public/jquery.sticky2e46.js?ver=3.9.2" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-05-03 12:12:54 +0800
cache: [GET /assets/lms/wp-content/themes/lms/framework/js/public/jquery.nicescroll.min2e46.js?ver=3.9.2] stale, valid, store


cache: [GET /assets/lms/wp-content/themes/lms/framework/js/public/jquery.sticky2e46.js?ver=3.9.2] stale, valid, store
Started GET "/assets/lms/wp-content/themes/lms/framework/js/public/jquery.isotope.min2e46.js?ver=3.9.2" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-05-03 12:12:54 +0800
```

I tried the following setting but it didn't work.

## initial/assets.rb

```
Rails.cache.silence!
```

## development.rb

```
  # Show full error reports and disable caching.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send.
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Raise an error on page load if there are pending migrations.
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

  # Debug mode disables concatenation and preprocessing of assets.
  # This option may cause significant delays in view rendering with a large
  # number of complex assets.
  config.assets.debug = false
```

Answer (score 2):

To turn off the cache messages you just need to set verbose to false in your Rack::Cache config.  For example in production.rb, along with your other settings

```
  config.action_dispatch.rack_cache = { verbose: false }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the Logger class to introduce your custom behavior (ignore all Cache logs).  Here's a great write up to help you do the same: 
[Disable Rails Cache Logging](http://heliom.ca/blog/posts/disable-rails-cache-logging)

Comment: your solution doesn't work `cache: [GET /assets/welcome.js] stale, valid, store
[22888] 127.0.0.1 - - [03/May/2015 23:35:13] "GET /welcome.js HTTP/1.1" 304 - 0.0217
cache: [GET /assets/lms/wp-content/plugins/events-calendar-`